# JSON Parsing with dynamic Data

Tags: ios, json, uipickerview

**Hey Everyone,**
My problem is,I want to parse this string using JSON
http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=USD&to=EUR

but this is static that is it would convert from USD to EUR but what I want is the first parameter should be the one selected in first textField and the second from the second one.So that i can pass the commonISOCurrencyCodes(from the parameters selected in TF), to that string and get the result on click of a button on the Result TextField.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So what precisely is the question? How to get the currency code from your picker? How to build the string that will become the basis of the URL?

Comment: @Rob : Yup when i get the data from picker i want to pass it as a parameter to the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as simple as:

```
NSString* fromCode = // from
NSString* toCode = // to
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://rate-exchange.appspot.com/currency?from=%@&to=%@", fromCode, toCode];
```

Comment: Maniak : Thank You so much , Friend. That Worked Awesome.